# Dynamic HTML Table With DataTable not paginating

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, datatables

I have an html table that is generated in the following structure:

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-inverse table-bordered table-hover' id='LeaderBoardTable' table_Dynamic >";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th></th>";
echo "<th>Username</th>";
echo "<th>SteamID</th>";
echo "<th>Score</th>";
echo "<th>K/D</th>";
//echo "<th>Search</th>"; //Do later
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody id='leaderboardTable' class='leaderboardTable'>";
foreach ($items as $item){
    $player = new Player($item['steam'], $dbh);
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><i class='fa fa-crosshairs' aria-hidden='true'></i></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $player->get("name") . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $player->get("steam") . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $player->get("score") . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . getKD($player) . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</tbody>\n</table>";
```

The table loads fine and the javascript to insert it into the document looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'control/leaderboard/leaderboardGrab.php',
        data: 'null=null',
    }).done(function(d){
        $('#loadArea').html(d);
        $('#LeaderBoardTable').DataTable({
            "order": [[3, "desc"]],
            "bPaginate": true,
        });
    });

});
```

The table itself loads fine and the `.DataTable()` function "works" as in the table has the arrows next to it for sorting and the search box and number of items display are all there and work perfectly but the pagination does not seem to work although it does appear and show the right number of pages. Currently it shows [1][2][3][4][5][...][307] so it does have the right amount of pages but I can't click on any of the numbers to go to that page. Below is the full page that calls the generation code as well as has all the file calls in the head.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> <?php echo $webTitle; ?> </title>
    <?php $page = "leaderboards" //setting page for include ?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Calling JS -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified Jquery JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/DataTable/jqueryDataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="js/DataTable/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/leaderboard/leaderboardFunctions.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 and Tether -->
    <script src="js/tether/tether.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="js/Navjs.js"></script>
    <script src="js/paging.js"></script>

    <!-- End Of JS -->

    <!-- Bootstrap 4, Tether, Fontawesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/DataTable/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tether/tether.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/social.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS --> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once "views/social.php" ?>
<div class="container" style="width:95%;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <?php include_once "views/nav/index.php" ?>

            <?php include_once "views/$page/index.php" ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why it is not working? 90% of DataTables is working but pagination is not working and that appears the be the only part that is not working.

Only Console Error I get is missing Favicon.ico.

Thanks!

Comment: There are no errors related to the DataTables the errors produced are included now in the bottom of my post. Also I can make a fiddle but I can't make dynamic content can I? I am not sure if static content would work but all of my content I am using for this site is dynamically generated based off data in a database.

Comment: Fixed all console errors but missing favicon and error still happening, this is Bootstrap 4 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to which files I included, I tried with CDN's and it worked mostly except for some styling so I downloaded the same files as CDN and jquery-ui and added and seems to be working.